# Copy Google Apps Script from template spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a template spreadsheet which had a Google Apps Script embedded in it. I called it "Master Script". Then I created a copy of the template and noticed that the script also got copied over as "Copy of Master Script".

However, recently I observed that the master script is not getting copied over. Did Google make a change to disable the copy of the master script? How can I get this functionality back again now?

Comment: I have noticed the same issue. I have various method to copy the spreadsheets (via google app script or via direct google docs API in python) and from time to time I notice that the copy misses the script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there have been any changes.  I've noticed that some of my copies don't copy scripts over properly.  It gives some kind of error ("There was a problem with the copy" or something), and that seems to be consistent from my POV when scripts aren't copied.  If you notice it consistently I would open an issue with [Google Apps Script issue log](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)